# Android connect to Mysql in lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

hi i'm newbie to android. and i'm trying to android to connect mysql. 
i already wrote php file. and it works well.
but i don't know how to connect to mysql well.

i made readDB.php and writeDB.php. 
android's SendPost class use writeDB.php and phpDown class use readDB.php

when i run this screen appear short time and 'Unfortunatly test has stopped' massage appear.

below is logcat's error message.

```
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$phpDown.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:146)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at com.example.test.MainActivity$phpDown.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4512)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
02-05 16:03:16.233: E/AndroidRuntime(3188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is source code.

```
package com.example.test;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.*;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.*;
    import android.widget.*;
    import android.view.*;

    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
    import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        TextView txtView;
        phpDown task;
        ArrayList<ListItem> listItem= new ArrayList<ListItem>();
        String number = null;
        String passwords = null;
        Button button;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            task = new phpDown();
            txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);

            task.execute("http://203.255.70.229/readDB.php");

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String number_edit = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.number)).getText().toString();
                    String passwords_edit = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwords)).getText().toString();

                    number = number_edit;
                    passwords = passwords_edit;

                    new SendPost().execute();
                }
            });
        }

        private class SendPost extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> { 
            protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
                String content = executeClient();
                return content;
            }

            public String executeClient() { 
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> post = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number", number));
                post.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwords", passwords));

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 

                HttpParams params = client.getParams(); 
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000); //setSoTimeout?
                // Post객체 생성
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://203.255.70.229/writeDB.php");

                try {
                    UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(post,"UTF-8");
                    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
                    client.execute(httpPost);
                    return EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(entity);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        private class phpDown extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                StringBuilder jsonHtml = new StringBuilder(); //StringBuilder?
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urls[0]);

                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    if (conn != null) {
                        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                        conn.setUseCaches(false); //setUseCaches?

                        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")); //InputStreamReader?
                            for (;;) {
                                String line = br.readLine();
                                if (line == null)
                                    break;

                                jsonHtml.append(line + "\n"); 
                            }
                            br.close();
                        }
                        conn.disconnect();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return jsonHtml.toString();
            }


            protected void onPostExecute(String str) { 
                String number;
                String passwords;

                try {
                    JSONObject root = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONArray ja = root.getJSONArray("results"); 

                    for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                        number = jo.getString("number");
                        passwords = jo.getString("passwords");

                        listItem.add(new ListItem(number, passwords));;
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                txtView.setText("number:" + listItem.get(0).getData(0) + "\npasswords:"
                        + listItem.get(0).getData(1));
            }
        }
    }
```

any comment thanks

Comment: `listItem.get(0)` (in `onPostExecute`) what if the list is empty?

Comment: writeDB.php file have no problem. i think MainActivity.java can't connect to writeDB.php

Comment: You might want to make `readDB.php` return some valid JSON..

Comment: yes but i don't know much about post and json structure. so any comment thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To know whether the `phpDown` can connect to `writeDB.php`, print the `jsonHtml` out in the `doInBackground()`.  If it has the content from your `writeDB.php`, it means that it connects successfully.

But from your error log, the problem occurs in the `onPostExecute()`.  Check the following:

1. Is the string `jsonHtml` a valid `json` format?
2. Does `jsonHtml` contains the element `results` array?  You should have something like this `{results: [...]}` in your `jsonHtml`.

Comment: thank you. i solved problem and program is working. i didn't know about json's array and name,value structure. after i change php code properly android works.